# Pandas issue selecting row after grouping

Tags: pandas, group-by, aggregate

I am running into an issue that I'm surprised I have not had before.
Start with dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mrn':[263,263,263,273,273,273],'study_id':['st_1','st_1','st_1','st_2','st_2','st_2'],'data_categ':['pre_event','during_event','post_event','pre_event','during_event','post_event'],'data_val':[12,15,9,2,9,0]},columns=['mrn','study_id','data_categ','data_val'])
```

As expected, I can select specific rows with `df[df.mrn==263]` and I get the following output:

```
   mrn study_id    data_categ  data_val
0  263     st_1     pre_event        12
1  263     st_1  during_event        15
2  263     st_1    post_event         9
```

Now I want to group. I do the following:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["mrn","study_id","data_categ"]).agg({sum,np.median})
df2.columns = [df2.columns.get_level_values(1)+"_zz"]
df2=df2.reset_index()
```

This gives me the desired output:

```
>>> df2
   mrn study_id    data_categ sum_zz median_zz
0  263     st_1  during_event     15      15.0
1  263     st_1    post_event      9       9.0
2  263     st_1     pre_event     12      12.0
3  273     st_2  during_event      9       9.0
4  273     st_2    post_event      0       0.0
5  273     st_2     pre_event      2       2.0
```

HOWEVER, now when I try to select specific rows, I am not getting what I want:

```
>>> df2[df2.mrn==263]
     mrn study_id data_categ sum_zz median_zz
0  263.0      NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN
1  263.0      NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN
2  263.0      NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN
3    NaN      NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN
4    NaN      NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN
5    NaN      NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN
```

Why is this happening? why is it not returning only the rows that meet the condition (should be 3 of them) and the values in the rest of the columns?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to rename the columns by using the second-level values. Instead of concatenating them, the first-level values are being replaced with the second-level values.

The differences with @mozway answer primarily lie in the method of changing column names after aggregation and in explicitly specifying the column for applying aggregate functions. The results will be identical, and you can use either of these codes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'mrn': [263, 263, 263, 273, 273, 273], 'study_id': ['st_1', 'st_1', 'st_1', 'st_2', 'st_2', 'st_2'],
                   'data_categ': ['pre_event', 'during_event', 'post_event', 'pre_event', 'during_event', 'post_event'],
                   'data_val': [12, 15, 9, 2, 9, 0]}, columns=['mrn', 'study_id', 'data_categ', 'data_val'])

df2 = df.groupby(["mrn", "study_id", "data_categ"]).agg({"data_val": [sum, np.median]})
df2.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df2.columns]
df2 = df2.reset_index()

print(df2[df2.mrn == 263])
```

Output:

```
   mrn study_id    data_categ  data_val_sum  data_val_median
0  263     st_1  during_event            15             15.0
1  263     st_1    post_event             9              9.0
2  263     st_1     pre_event            12             12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

By using square brackets in `df2.columns = [df2.columns.get_level_values(1)+"_zz"]` you created a **MultiIndex** with one level, which further triggers your issue as only a Series can be used for boolean indexing of a whole DataFrame.

Remove them:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["mrn","study_id","data_categ"]).agg({sum,np.median})
df2.columns = df2.columns.get_level_values(1)+"_zz"
df2 = df2.reset_index()

print(df2[df2['mrn']==263])
```

Output:

```
   mrn study_id    data_categ  sum_zz  median_zz
0  263     st_1  during_event      15       15.0
1  263     st_1    post_event       9        9.0
2  263     st_1     pre_event      12       12.0
```

##### with square brackets

```
df2.columns
MultiIndex([(       'mrn',),
            (  'study_id',),
            ('data_categ',),
            (    'sum_zz',),
            ( 'median_zz',)],
           )

df2['mrn']  # this is a DataFrame
   mrn
0  263
1  263
2  263
3  273
4  273
5  273
```

##### without them

```
df2.columns
Index(['mrn', 'study_id', 'data_categ', 'sum_zz', 'median_zz'], dtype='object')

df2['mrn']  # this is a Series
0    263
1    263
2    263
3    273
4    273
5    273
Name: mrn, dtype: int64
```

##### better alternative

You can achieve the desired result automatically with:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(["mrn","study_id","data_categ"])['data_val'].agg({sum,np.median})
         .add_suffix('_zz').reset_index()
       )
```

Comment: I edited to add output, same as you) BTW this is not a complaint, I just need a rating. I'm too small fish among sharks like you

Answer (score 0):

Other answers mentioned here will work in general for every situation but if you are targeting only one column to be aggregated, the below solution would work.

When you are trying to do a group by, make sure you mention the target column for the aggregation

```
df2 = df.groupby(["mrn","study_id","data_categ"])['data_val'].agg({sum,np.median})
```

This way, the dataframe would not have a MultiIndex Columns when you reset the index

```
df2 = df2.reset_index()
print(df2[df2.mrn==263])
```

This will provide your expected result set